# NavigationView below status bar android 5+

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to implement the same behaviour on pre and after lolipop devices. The thing is that sdk 21 was implemented the feature to user status bar as the part of the application. That's why my Navigation header height is smaller that in sdk 15.
The solutiion is to use this parameters in styles 21:

```
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

but this will cause status bar to be a part of my application and I don't want such behaviour.
How to make navigation header of the same height with lolipop and pre lolipop devices?
pic is included.

[image]

Comment: doesn't anyone have even a clue how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in fitsSystemWindows parameter which is set not only in activity_main layout but inside app_bar_main.xml